# How does mvn package single grandchild modules?

Tags: java, maven

here is my project module tree:

```
project:
    module A
       module A1
       module A2
    module B
       module B1
       module B2
```

I know how to build module A, for example `mvnw clean package -pl A -am`

but try to build module A1 using `mvnw clean package -pl A1 -am` it will failed.

I also tried `mvnw clean package -pl A/A1 -am` it runs, but build all A including A1 & A2.

is it possible build A1 and its related module only?

Comment: First does your build work from root level (project?)... simply by using `mvn package`?

Comment: yes, build from root works fine.

Comment: If you like to build parts you have to initially do an `mvn clean install` from the root level afterwards you can do the things you have shown... (You migh try to use Apache Maven 4 alpha 7) which has a lot of improvements related to reactor...